# Fortran's MKL dgemm is giving zero result

Tags: fortran, matrix-multiplication, blas, intel-mkl

In the following Fortran program I use Intel's MKL library to perform matrix multiplications using `dgemm`. Initially, I used the `matmul` subroutine and got correct results. When I translated `matmul` to `dgemm` in the loop below, I got all zero vectors instead of the correct output. I appreciate your help.

```
program spectral_norm    
implicit none
!
integer, parameter :: n = 5500, dp = kind(0.0d0)
real(dp), allocatable :: A(:, :), u(:), v(:), Au(:), Av(:)
integer :: i, j

allocate(u(n), v(n), A(n, n), Au(n), Av(n))

do j = 1, n
    do i = 1, n
        A(i, j) = Ac(i, j)
    end do
end do

u = 1
do i = 1, 10
    call dgemm('N','N', n, 1, n, 1.0, A,  n, u, n, 0.0, Au, n) 
    call dgemm('N','N', n, 1, n, 1.0, Au, n, A, n, 0.0, v,  n) 
    call dgemm('N','N', n, 1, n, 1.0, A,  n, v, n, 0.0, Av, n) 
    call dgemm('N','N', n, 1, n, 1.0, Av, n, A, n, 0.0, u,  n) 
    !v = matmul(matmul(A, u), A)
    !u = matmul(matmul(A, v), A)
end do

write(*, "(f0.9)") sqrt(dot_product(u, v) / dot_product(v, v))

contains

pure real(dp) function Ac(i, j) result(r)
integer, intent(in) :: i, j
r = 1._dp / ((i+j-2) * (i+j-1)/2 + i)
end function

end program spectral_norm
```

This gives `NaN`, while the correct output from `matmul` is `1.274224153`.

Comment: Use MKL modules. Tjey can help you identify many errors and also contain simple Fortran 90 interfaces to those subroutines.

Comment: @VladimirF --  I don't think it is a missing-modules problem. I have set the `include directories` in VStudio properly and set the `Use MKL` option. If I try to multiply any other two matrices, it works. For example `call dgemm('t', 'n', n, n, n, 1.0, A,  n, A, n, 0.0, A, n)` gives the correct matrix.

Comment: I think you should use 1.d0 and 0.d0 because you are using dgemm which require double precision arguments. `dgemm ('N','N', n, 1, n, 1.d0, A,  n, u, n, 0.d0, Au, n)`

Comment: @VladimirF -- You may be correct, when I add `use MKL` I get this `error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [MKL]`. So, what can I do now?

Comment: you can include file: `include 'blas.f90' `

Comment: Actually, the include in this case includes two modules and must be placed outside of the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, thank you all for your suggestions. I think I figured out the source of the error. The order of multiplication was reversed in two cases, it should have been `A * Au` and `A * Av` instead. This is because `A` has order `n x n` and both `Au` ans `Av` have order `n x 1`. So, we can't multiply `Au * A` or `Av * A` due to dimensions mismatch. I posted the corrected version below.

```
program spectral_norm    
implicit none
!
integer, parameter :: n = 5500, dp = kind(0.d0)
real(dp), allocatable :: A(:,:), u(:), v(:), Au(:), Av(:)
integer :: i, j

allocate(u(n), v(n), A(n, n), Au(n), Av(n))

do j = 1, n
    do i = 1, n
        A(i, j) = Ac(i, j)
    end do
end do

u = 1
do i = 1, 10
    call dgemm('N', 'N', n, 1, n, 1._dp, A, n, u,  n, 0._dp, Au, n)
    call dgemm('T', 'N', n, 1, n, 1._dp, A, n, Au, n, 0._dp, v,  n)
    call dgemm('N', 'N', n, 1, n, 1._dp, A, n, v,  n, 0._dp, Av, n)
    call dgemm('T', 'N', n, 1, n, 1._dp, A, n, Av, n, 0._dp, u,  n)
end do

write(*, "(f0.9)") sqrt(dot_product(u, v) / dot_product(v, v))

contains

pure real(dp) function Ac(i, j) result(r)
    integer, intent(in) :: i, j
    r = 1._dp / ((i+j-2) * (i+j-1)/2 + i)
end function

end program spectral_norm
```

This gives the correct results:

```
1.274224153
 Elapsed time   0.5150000     seconds
```